# How to tell if an element of a list was clicked in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

how do I know if an element of a list was clicked in javascript?

```
<div id="list">
<a href="#">one</a>
<a href="#">two</a>
<a href="#">three</a>
</div>
```

with Jquery is:

```
$('#list a')
```

JavaScript and how do I do?

Answer (score 8):

You can use delegated event handling that takes advantage of event propagation so you put one event handler on the parent and it sees all the events from the children:

```
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // e.target will be the item that was clicked on
    e.target.style.color = "#F00";
})
```

Or, you could attach an event handler to each link directly by enumerating the links that are children of the list:

```
var links = querySelectorAll("#list a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    this.style.color = "#F00";
})
```

---

FYI, if programming in plain javascript, I find it very useful to use a few utility functions that help you iterate lists of HTML objects which are often returned from DOM functions:

```
// do a querySelectorAll() and then call a function on each item
// the parent argument is optional (defaults to document)
function iterateQuerySelectorAll(selector, fn, parent) {
    parent = parent || document;
    var items = parent.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        fn(items[i]);
    }
}

// add an event handler to each item that matches a selector
// the parent argument is optional (defaults to document)
function addEventQuerySelectorAll(selector, event, fn, parent) {
    iterateQuerySelectorAll(selector, function(item) {
        item.addEventListener(event, fn);
    }, parent);
}
```

Then, with these utility helpers, the second example of code above would simply be this:

```
addEventQuerySelectorAll("#list a", "click", function() {
    this.style.color = "#F00";
});
```

Comment: how would i know the index of the element selected in a list?